# Replace part of string between two spaces

Tags: javascript

I have some string in this format XX XXXX XX XXX. How I can, using javascript, replace the part of string which is between first and second space to get this kind of output string XX YYYY XX XXX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing a regex replacement with `replace()`, in non global mode, which would therefore target just the first match in the input string.

```js
var input = "XX XXXX XX XXX";
var output = input.replace(/ \w+/, " YYYY");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using split and join easily

```
let input = "XX XXXX XX XXX";
let arr = input.split(' ');
arr[1] = 'YYYY'
let output = arr.join(' ') 

console.log(output) //'XX YYYY XX XXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="text">XX XXXX XX XXX!</p>

<script>
let t = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = t.replace("XXXX", "YYYY");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

using js split and join will get this done example

```
let string = 'XX XXXX XX XXX'
let newString = string.split(' '); //split string to array with space within
newString[1] = 'YYYY'; //overwrite the value of second text in string
newString.join(' '); //join the array text back with space
```